# Eigenspaces of $A^TA$ has dimension 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any matrix A, I'm rather sure that all eigenspaces of $A^TA$, which are $\ker(A^TA-\lambda I)$ with $\lambda$ being any eigenvalue of $A^TA$, has dimension 1. But I'm stuck to prove this. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $A=I$..........

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I know that comments require a minimum of 15 characters, but I think that just typing "........" is a bit disrespectful to the OP... Especially when it takes the same time to write something like "It's simple: $A=I$" instead :^)

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you David and Ottavio as well :-D